# Excel VBA check if shortcut xls file is pointing to valid file

Tags: vba, excel, error-handling

I have got some code that loops through each file stored in the network drive folder. The files I'm looping through are shortcuts to files located in various other folders on the shared drive.

My code is working but there are some shortcut files that throw up a "missing shortcut" and asks me to browse the filesystem. Now I'm not allowed to remove the files/shortcuts. Is there any why i can access where the shortcut's pointing to so i can test if the file exists

I tried:

```
Dim oFSO as object
Dim Folder as object
Dim Files as object
Dim file as Object

Set oFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set Folder = oFSO.GetFolder(thisWorkbook.Path)

For each file in Folders.files
  On Error GoTo fileErr:
  Workbooks.Open file.Path

  On Error GoTo 0
   Msgbox "File is opened"
   GoTo nextFile

fileErr:
  Msgbox Err.Description

nextFile:
Next file
```

Any help appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Use a function like below :

```
Public Sub checkShortCut()
    MsgBox GetTargetPath("<Path>\<filename>.lnk")
    /*Your Code Here*/
End Sub

Function GetTargetPath(ByVal FileName As String)

    Dim Obj As Object
    Dim Shortcut As Object

    Set Obj = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    Set Shortcut = Obj.CreateShortcut(FileName)
    GetTargetPath = Shortcut.TargetPath
    Shortcut.Save

End Function
```